# How to show disabled textfields on a form?

Tags: usability, forms, input

I have an HTML form with some textfields and datetime fields. Some elements should be shown readonly for a user group. Unfortunately, site's base color is gray so I could not use that color for the invalid elements. What else can I use for that function?

Comment: Could you show what the form looks like when not disabled? It would help giving the visual nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

At issue is not the particular color you choose but rather that you indicate to the user that the element is read-only. The UX part is telling users that this element functions differently than other elements (and of course gray is the color normally used for this purpose).

Ultimately this is more of a question for your graphic designers and, by the way, grays can still work very well even if your background color is gray.

Comment: agreed.  here is an ugly example, but it works.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxpv.png  I think gray works pretty well in this example, because it blends into the background without disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce some color to your form inputs such as border or placeholder color and then lower the opacity when disabled. You can also toy with overlaying a "disabled" looking background to the input field.

[image]